# Differentiable analogue of greatest integer (a.k.a. floor) function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) is not differentiable at integral values in the real domain. However, we can build a new function defined as:
$$x+\left(\frac{2}{1+\exp{(-k \sin(\pi x))}}-1\right)\frac{\arcsin(\cos(\pi x))}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$$
As shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1kvtsn8ags), for large values of $k$, the function is a pretty good approximation of the floor function, with the added benefit of it being smooth and continuous. The function was built with a mix of the sigmoid function with a repeating triangular signal function.
[image]

The only problem with my function is that as $k$ tends to infinity, integer values $n$ are mapped to $n+0.5$ instead of $n$

Now my question is this: **What other smooth and continuous functions can be used to approximate the floor function?**

Additional context: This question came to my mind when I read about the [swish function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swish_function) being better than the
[ReLU function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) for being differentiable.

Comment: You can use a [mollifier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) to convolute the step function with, and obtain a $C^\infty$ approximation.

Comment: I hadn’t heard of the mollifier before, but it seems that it should do the job. Also what do you mean by a $C^{\infty}$ approximation?

Comment: I mean that by using a molifier, you can obtain a $C^\infty$ (smooth) function, which approximates the floor function well.

Comment: Ah, @Kolja , so you are referring to the [order of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) right?

Comment: @Kolja also, as I am unaware of the computational efficiency of the mollifier convolution, which one do you think would be computationally faster? The function in my question or your one? Not that computational efficiency is my goal, but just curious…

Comment: Yes, order of continuity is classical mathematical terminology, the infinitely derivable functions being smooth functions. 
As for the computational efficiency, I am not sure. The mollifier requires evaluating a bump function inside an integral which is then computed. So there is a computational overhead with respect to simply evaluating a function. 
If you really want to compute them, what is the point of having smooth functions, why not just use something continuous or differentiable once or twice? Convolutions can be sped up with FFT, but I'm not sure what's the overhead wrt your method.

Comment: @Kolja actually by [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) I was referring to the function possessing at least $C^1$ continuity. But I think I have got your point.

Comment: I have always considered smooth to be $C^\infty$, though I see now that my terminology differs from Wikipedia's. For $C^1$ I'm not sure what would be the optimal approach, but note that it is enough to compute an approximation for a single step, and the rest can be computed by shifting. So if $g:[-1/2, 1/2] \rightarrow [-1,0]$ is a single $C^1$ step function, then $f:x \mapsto g(\{x\}) + \lceil x \rfloor$ is also $C^1$, where $x = \{x\} + \lceil x \rfloor$ with some rounding function.

Comment: @Kolja my intention was to look for more ways of approaching the same problem. Your approach was quite new to me, and the mollifier was a great addition to my ‘mathematical arsenal’. I think [summing up sigmoids](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pxfbgnbtls) (displaced by unit values) should also do the trick?

Comment: That is an awfully inefficient function to compute. Also, it is not defined everywhere, you need $a\to \infty$ which becomes tricky to manipulate. If you want to compute it at, say $n=2^50$ you would need to do way too many sums. A simpler way is to define, say a sigmoid $g(x)$ in $[1/2, 3/2]$ so that it has derivative equal to $0$ at $1/2, 3/2$, and then set $f(x) = g(x - \lfloor x \rfloor + 1/2) + \lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2$ which becomes also $C^1$ and much easier to compute.

Comment: I think I had already mentioned that my target was _not_ computational efficiency. I was just looking for more perspectives to the same problem, and yes, I agree that your function is much more computationally efficient.

Comment: Indeeed you did, I misread. In any case I think it's still useful to think about the example that I provided.

As for your _sum of sigmoids_, there are things that you should be careful about. If you want to have an everywhere defined step function approximation, then you should use an infinite sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}1/(1+e^{k(n-x)})$. But it is not obvious (if you don't have enough experience) that this sum converges and is well defined. So, from a theoretical perspective, this should be addressed.